# Graph API for Sharepoint site viewed or accessed

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I need to keep track of the SharePoint site that is viewed or accessed by anyone.

I have tried some graph API's

1. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site-id/drives/drive-id/items('item-id')/activities](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site-id/drives/drive-id/items(%27item-id%27)/activities) - This API provides details about the user who created or modified a file, but it does not provide information about users who accessed or viewed the document.
2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site-id/analytics - This API returns the number of views for activity statistics but does not provide details about individual users who accessed the document.
3. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used - While attempting to use this API, it was observed that it utilizes either the 'me' endpoint or 'user'. However, it does not seem to directly provide information on the specific documents accessed or viewed, along with user details.

Is there any Microsoft Graph API that provides information about documents that have been accessed or viewed, including details about the users who accessed them?